# What am I? - Easy

Tags: riddle

I’m found in your yard but I’m not grass
I move slowly but I’m not a sloth
I have a shell but I’m not an egg
I’m slimy but I’m not a slug
I’m eaten by French people but I’m not frog’s legs

What am I?

Comment: I'd say the words "much too" are missing from the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The animal you are is

> A snail.

I’m found in your yard but I’m not grass

> Snails are usually found in yards

I move slowly but I’m not a sloth
I have a shell but I’m not an egg

> Snails move slow and have shells

I’m slimy but I’m not a slug
I’m eaten by French people but I’m not frog’s legs

> Snails are slimy and the French eat them